# Firefox on Arch Linux always asks about download destination

Tags: linux, arch-linux, firefox, download

I, actualy, don't know where to ask this, but this can be related to Linux.

**Firefox on Arch Linux always asks about download destination**, even if there's a default download destination folder set up through options interface or even about:config.

**How can I fix that?**

*Additional info:*

It's been normal till 22.0. I've tried to re-create profile or even create new, clean one, and try there and still got the same problem.

I've also tried to ask this question on #firefox @ freenode, but haven't got any reply.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on SuperUser?

Comment: I wasn't sure where to post this, so, I've posted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the address bar, and type `about:config`. Accept the following warranty void notification and proceed.

You will now see a list of preferences. Right click anywhere, and select `New` to create a new preference. Set the preference name as `browser.download.dir` and the preference value as your destination directory -- say, `/home/user/my_files`. Now, if your type in the preference name in the search bar above, the new entry will be displayed.

Now, in the above search bar, type `browser.download.folderList`. Double click on the entry displayed below, and change the value to `2`.

Now, try downloading any file, and check if it works. It at least worked for me.

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=802592

Further information about:config entries: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries